# How to send an array inside a structure of XDR through socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, xdr

I'm trying to send chunks of data from a file using an array declared inside a structure  through XDR. The idea is to establish a client server communication encoded with XDR.

```
struck response{
float data[5];
bool error;
}myreq;
```

I may have to use the following functions but i'm not sure. If yes, in which order?

```
xdrmem_create()
xdrstdio_create()
xdr_array()
```

Note: Am using C language in linux environment.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should use xdr_`xdrrec_create()`, providing your own read and write routines that read to/write from the socket. You should then write, or generate, an `xdr_response()` method for your `struct response` that calls `xdr_array()` for the array and `xdr_bool()` for the boolean.